# OTRS AD authentication based on username

Tags: otrs

I have configured otrs open source edition to authenticate based on email address of user on customer page.Is there is any way we can authenticate based on their username ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

What is your authentication backend for the OTRS ( DB, LDAP, BASIC )

In case it is DB, then please add these lines in Kernel/Config.pm

```
$Self->{'Customer::AuthModule'}                       = 'Kernel::System::CustomerAuth::DB';
$Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::DB::Table'}            = 'customer_user';
$Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::DB::CustomerKey'}      = 'login';
```

It will set the required customerKey to login column o the table customer_user

UPDATE #1

Well, in this case edit your Config.pm file and add these lines:

Pay attention to variables LDAP::UID, CustomerKey and mapping for UserCustomerID. Review your AD and make sure, that EVERY customer, has unique value in sAMAccountName

```
 $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::UID'} = 'sAMAccountName';

 $Self->{CustomerUser} = {
      Module => 'Kernel::System::CustomerUser::LDAP',
      Params => {
      Host => 'host.example.com',
      BaseDN => 'OU=BaseOU,DC=example,DC=com',
      SSCOPE => 'sub',
      UserDN =>'otrs_ldap',
      UserPw => 'PASSWORD',
    },
# customer unique id
    CustomerKey => 'sAMAccountName',
    # customer #
    CustomerID => 'mail',
    CustomerUserListFields => ['sAMAccountName', 'cn', 'mail'],
    CustomerUserSearchFields => ['sAMAccountName', 'cn', 'mail'],
    CustomerUserSearchPrefix => '',
    CustomerUserSearchSuffix => '*',
    CustomerUserSearchListLimit => 250,
    CustomerUserPostMasterSearchFields => ['mail'],
    CustomerUserNameFields => ['givenname', 'sn'],
    Map => [
      # note: Login, Email and CustomerID needed!
      # var, frontend, storage, shown, required, storage-type
      #[ 'UserSalutation', 'Title', 'title', 1, 0, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserFirstname', 'Firstname', 'givenname', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserLastname', 'Lastname', 'sn', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserLogin', 'Login', 'sAMAccountName', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserEmail', 'Email', 'mail', 1, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserCustomerID', 'CustomerID', 'sAMAccountName', 0, 1, 'var' ],
      [ 'UserPhone', 'Phone', 'telephonenumber', 1, 0, 'var' ],
      #[ 'UserAddress', 'Address', 'postaladdress', 1, 0, 'var' ],
      #[ 'UserComment', 'Comment', 'description', 1, 0, 'var' ],
    ],
  };
```

Comment: My authentication backend for the OTRS customer is LDAP with mail as filter which otrs uses for authentication.Is there is a way so otrs can authenticate only based on user's login name.

Comment: Yes my main problem is that in our AD user's email filed is left blank,so we have to authenticate based on only username.That means we don't require user's email ID on AD.